# How change a value of another class?

Tags: class, actionscript-3, variables, angle, projectile

I have an enemy class and a bullet class.

The enemies are added programmatically, and they handle their own movements within their class file.

How would I go about making them shoot bullets?

In the bullet class, there are some variables.

speed
angle
etc

But how can I get the proper angle? I need the angle to be based on the rotation of the particular enemy shooting the bullet.

So I need to add something like this to the bullet class file:

" if enemy is shooting blablaba
addChild(this)
angle = ((((((based on the enemies rotation?))))))

How do I do it? I have no idea how to refer to variables in other classes..

I know about _root., but that is irrelevant now.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, your `Player` might have a `fire()` function that deals with this.

As an extremely simple example of that, you might have:

```
public function fire():void
{
    var bullet:Bullet = new Bullet(x, y, rotation);
    stage.addChild(bullet);
}
```

Where your `Bullet` would accept the starting position and rotation:

```
class Bullet extends Sprite
{
    public function Bullet(x:int, y:int, rotation:Number)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.rotation = rotation;
    }
}
```

This makes it easy to advance your `fire()` function to deal with things like the Player having a different weapon, no ammunition, etc:

```
public function fire():void
{
    if(currentWeapon.ammunition === 0) return;

    if(currentWeapon is Handgun)
    {
        // Make a HandgunBullet.
    }

    if(currentWeapon is Shotgun)
    {
        // Make a ShotgunBullet.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!

However, I get a small error. The bullets fire just fine, but if I try to check for collisions,

   if(this.hitTestObject(_root.assassin.hitbox))
       {
        _root.hitPoints -= 30;
        this.parent.removeChild(this);
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
       }

Then I get a 1009 error.

And also, I get a weird 1063 error in the main class.

Comment: @user3123633 The code provided is only rough to give you an idea. Also, I don't think `_root` exists in AS3.

Comment: Same happens with

   if(this.x < 0 || this.x > _root.stageWidth || this.y > _root.stageWidth || this.y < 0)
   {
    removeChild(this);
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
   }

:(

Comment: I use it like this
          private var _root:MovieClip;

and then in the constructor
   _root = MovieClip(root);